# Показ кнопки меню на small разрешении. Navbar bootsrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Мне нужно активировать показ кнопки вызова мобильного меню на sm разрешении, можно ли так сделать избежав смены точек медиа запросов. Спасибо

Comment: Не понятно что именно вы имеете ввиду. Дополните вопрос кодом - как у вас сейчас и например скрином чего хотите добиться и тогда вам можно будет помочь.

Comment: Да. Можно. С помощью javascript.